# Java layer separation circular dependencies between modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, layer

I'm making an assignment for school and I need to implement layer separation in my program.
I made a litte game called Space Invaders. It works but when I try to separate things into modules I keep getting the message in IntelliJ.

*Adding dependency on module business will introduce circular depency between modules audio and business*

I also made an attempt to separate the dataaccess layer with the business layer. After fighting for several hours I have it working. But had to delete the module-info.java. Which isn't a good thing.
I must be overlooking something. To make it a bit visual :)

A first start with my layer separation:
[Layer separation drawing]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT9FC.png

[Classdiagram]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imYI3.png

And of course the code :) It a bit too big to post here, so here is the link to GIT.

https://github.com/Koffiemolen/SpaceInvaders.git

I try to separate dataccess HighscoreStore and the SoundFactory. SoundFactory is in de the audio module.

If I'm using terms incorrect please let me know. I'm still learning ;-)

Comment: I forgot to mention, if you want to run the game. Moduel main → bootstrap → Game.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would better fit into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rkosegi In the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus* (as I have done here), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353). In the current form the post would be [off-topic on CR because the code is not embedded directly](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/120114).

Answer (score 0):

Your circular dependency is between business and dataaccess - they depend on each other  typically your data access and audio shall depend on nothing,  and business gets dependency to both.

Dependency to JUnit shall have scope of test.

And while we are at it,   use maven or even better gradle -  this would be cool and portable way to build project.   and IDEA just grabs those project models and uses them natively

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The module-info.java was deleted but I still got messages about circular dependency.

In IntelliJ you can go to *Open module settings*, in this view you can set or delete dependencies.
[IntelliJ modules overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luOBO.png)

By this I found out that the class ControlledGameObject had a dependency on control module.

I thought it was only possible to set dependencies by module-info.java but they are also stored in the moduel iml file.